# What can cause computer to stretch 4:3 resolutions to widescreen?

Tags: resolution, aspect-ratio

One of my computers stretches fullscreen applications running in 4:3 resolution to widescreen. It appears that native 16:9 resolution is instantly changed back. This renders older PC games with no true widescreen support practically unplayable.
I'm unsure if this is done by the monitor (an LCD TV) or OS. Changing to a 4:3 resolution in Windows setting doesn't fix the issue.

---

PC specifications (no AMD drivers installed):

```
AMD Athlon II X2 245 processor
ATI Radeon 3000 graphics
2 GB RAM
Windows 10
```

Comment: I don't currently have more detailed specifications to give - I will provide later if needed as the machine is located in a distant location.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/122730/display-stretches-43-ratios-adds-scrolling-to-other-ratios), I don't have a multi-monitor setup.